# Incorrect Regex.Split scan

Tags: .net, regex

I'm having a problem with this expression: `;(?!.*(\}|""|')|(\{|""|'))` and the problem is this:

**This is the original string:**

```
abc; def; lalala;
123;
456;
789;
'some string with ; on center';
'an string;
new line;
chars;';
{
this;
doens't;
be;
detected;
};
```

**This is what I Want:**

```
index      item
---------- --------------------
0          abc
1          def
2          lalala
3          123
4          456
5          789
6          'Some string with ; on center'
7          'an string;
           new line; 
           chars;'
8          {
           this;
           doens't;
           be;
           detected;
           }
```

**But, this is what is returned...**

```
index      item
---------- --------------------
0          abc
1          def
2          lalala
3          123
4          456
5          789
6          'Some string with ; on center'
7          'an string;
8          new line
9          chars;'
           {
10         this;
11         doens't;
12         be;
13         detected;
           }
```

This Regex I can't obtain the lines of a file as described above, and I've tested it on several online regex debuggers, didn't get any method. I'm using the SingleLine option, but they worsen things. Any idea? Where is the error? Where can I upgrade for the way I want?

This is some part of my code (In VB.NET):

```
Public Shared Sub runApplication(ByVal appString As String)
  Dim lines As String() = regex.Split(appString, ";(?!.*(\}|""|')|(\{|""|'))")
  Const iStart$ = "^[\t\s]*"
  Const iSpaceTab = "[\t\s]*"
  Const iProperty As System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions = Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.None
  'set Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase to ignore case language
  Dim varList As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
  Dim constList As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

  For i As UInt64 = 0 To lines.Length - 1
     Dim X As String = lines(i)
     lastItem = X
 '........
```

*I'm using Visual Basic .NET,
.NET Framework 4.5*

Comment: Where's the code you're using to generate that?

Comment: It looks like the main issue is that the string which is split on multiple lines is treated as multiple strings; it should be fairly simple to join those back together so they are one string (with line breaks).

Comment: and what i can do to fix it?

Comment: Looking at how you want `;` as a separator but want it not to be a separator when in between an opening and closing element like `'` suggests that you almost want a grammar. Regex is not meant for parsing grammars, so please be aware, that you might need to do some post processing, because regex cannot make a difference between line 1 and line 4 in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `RegEx.Split`, why not just create a pattern that matches the strings that you are specifically looking for?  For instance, something like this:

```
(?<=^|\n|;\s*)({[^}]*}|'[^']*'|.*?)(?=;)
```

See a [working example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5E%7C%5Cn%7C%3B%5Cs*)(%7B%5B%5E%7D%5D*%7D%7C%27%5B%5E%27%5D*%27%7C.*%3F)(%3F%3D%3B)&i=abc%3B%20def%3B%20lalala%3B%0D%0A123%3B%0D%0A456%3B%0D%0A789%3B%0D%0A%27some%20string%20with%20%3B%20on%20center%27%3B%0D%0A%27an%20string%3B%0D%0Anew%20line%3B%0D%0Achars%3B%27%3B%0D%0A%7B%0D%0Athis%3B%0D%0Adoens%27t%3B%0D%0Abe%3B%0D%0Adetected%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B).

Then all you need to do is get the matches an loop through them:

```
For Each m As Match In RegEx.Matches(appString, "(?<=^|\n|;\s*)({[^}]*}|'[^']*'|.*?)(?=;)")
    Dim line As String = m.Value
    ' ...
Next
```

Comment: You are a God of regular expressions? Thank you very much!